# Extracting values from an array using a logical array

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, indexing

I have the following MATLAB code which I would like to replicate using Python.

The MATLAB code creates a logical array for when `xDiff == 2` and then uses that logical array to extract corresponding values from the `tDiff` array to create the resulting array, `tTacho`.

MATLAB code:

```
tTacho = tDiff(xDiff == 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) with NumPy.
For example:

```
import numpy as np

x_diff = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2])
t_diff = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

print(t_diff[x_diff == 2])
```

gives:

```
array([1, 2, 5])
```

---

If you don't want to use NumPy, then you can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
x_diff = [0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2]
t_diff = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print([t for t, x in zip(t_diff, x_diff) if x == 2])
```

gives:

```
[1, 2, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list indexing also.

```
 tDiff=[1,2,4,5,6,6,7]
 xDiff=[2,3,2,2,2,2,2]
 for x in range(0,len(xDiff)):
     if xDiff[x]==2:
        print tDiff[x]
```

If this helps.